# How to handle a page refresh using html 5 mode & Spring webflux

Tags: spring-webflux, angular-router

I am trying to implement a technique described here: [use html5 mode with servlets](https://spring.io/blog/2015/05/13/modularizing-the-client-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-vii#using-ldquo-natural-rdquo-routes) with webflux.

In a nutshell, users need to be able to refresh a page from their browser without being redirected to the `404` whitelabel page from Spring Boot.

The tutorial above relies on a technique using servlets' `forward:` mechanism:

```
@Controller
public class ForwardController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/**/{[path:[^\\.]*}")
    public String redirect() {
        // Forward to home page so that route is preserved.
        return "forward:/";
    }
}
```

However I use **webflux** and not **servlets**. Here is what I have tried using a `WebFilter`:

```
@Component
public class SpaWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        String path = exchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath();
        if (!path.startsWith("/api") && path.matches("[^\\\\.]*")) {
            return chain.filter(
                exchange.mutate().request(exchange.getRequest().mutate().path("/").build()
                ).build());
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

When the user refreshes the page, this results in a `404`.

**edit**: Let me describe the issue in more details:

Once the SPA is loaded in the browser, the user can navigate using the angular route links. Say from  `http://localhost:8080/` to `http://localhost:8080/user-list` (here `/user-list` is an angular route. This navigation has no interaction with the backend.

Now when the user - still on the `/user-list` route - chooses to refresh the browser page, Spring is going to try to resolve the `/user-list` path to a backend handler/router function and this will result in a 404 whitelabel error page served from Spring Boot.

What I want to achieve is that the `http://localhost:8080/user-list` page is still  displayed to the user when they refresh the browser page.

**edit 2**: Please note that this refresh issue does not occur on the index page (`http://localhost:8080/`) because I have implemented this filter:

```
@Component
public class IndexWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        if (exchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath().equals("/")) {
            return chain.filter(
                exchange.mutate().request(exchange.getRequest().mutate().path("/index.html").build()
                ).build()
            );
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

It is obviously not feasible to implement one such filter for each of my Angular routes...

**edit 3**: Please also note that this issue occurs because the frontend is served as a jar on the backend classpath with the following config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class WebConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/").addResourceLocations("classpath:/index.html");
    }
}
```

In other words, I don't use a frontend proxy nor a reverse proxy (e.g. nginx)

Comment: you are getting a 404 because you are catching the request to the server in a filter, mutating the path to "/" and then letting the request continue into the application. The application then tries to find an endpoint in your application on path "/" but you have no endpoint defined there.

You need either skip the filter and create an endpoint that instead returns a HttpStatusCode of 301 or locate the url in a filter and throw a `ResponseStatusException` with the status code 301 to redirect the browser.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasAndolf. Are you sure I actually need to do a redirect on the browser side ? The servlet's forward mechanism does nothing on the browser side. On the contrary, it is meant to be invisible to the browser and happen on the server only.

Comment: I dont really get what it is you want to do you are very unclear. Do you wish to redirect all incoming client requests to "/" in the backend application. because that is what you are doing now and you have nothing in your backend application on "/" thats why you get a 404 please explain more clearly what it is you want to do.

Comment: I have edited my post as requested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the solution to my issue. What I was getting wrong was the value of the url "forwarded" to.

By using `/index.html` instead of `/`, the app behaves as expected.

```
@Component
public class SpaWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        String path = exchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath();
        if (!path.startsWith("/api") && path.matches("[^\\\\.]*")) {
            return chain.filter(
                exchange.mutate().request(exchange.getRequest().mutate().path("/index.html").build()
                ).build());
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

The same can be achieved with NGINX as follows:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

This assumes that the angular routes must not contain any dot and must not start with `/api` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution I found which works:

https://github.com/emmapatterson/webflux-kotlin-angular/blob/master/README.md

Hope this helps!
The main code is:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono

private const val INDEX_FILE_PATH = "/index.html"

@Configuration
internal class StaticContentConfiguration(): WebFilter {

    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        val path = exchange.request.uri.path
        if (pathMatchesWebAppResource(path)) {
            return redirectToWebApp(exchange, chain)
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange)
    }

    private fun redirectToWebApp(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain) = 
    chain.filter(exchange.mutate()
        .request(exchange.request.mutate().path(INDEX_FILE_PATH).build())
        .build())

    private fun pathMatchesWebAppResource(path: String) =
        !path.startsWith("/api") && path.matches("[^\\\\.]*".toRegex())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve it through web flux Router function, please find sample code below

```
@Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> htmlRouter(@Value("classpath:/static/index.html") Resource html) {
        return route(
                GET("/"),
                request -> ok()
                        .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        .bodyValue(html)
        );
    }
```

Comment: Good idea. However, doesn't work with spring security, i.e. sub-request like e.g. polyfills - <...>.js return 401.

Comment: copy all required files to the resource/static folder and provide a path of static folder in index.html file. I'm doing same way in angular and its working fine

Comment: What du you mean with “provide a path of static folder”?

Comment: sorry I misunderstood. For spring-security please allow js file without authentication like 

http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/", "/actuator/**", "/*.js", "/*.css",
      "/*.woff*", "/*.eot*", "/*.ttf*", "/*.svg*", "/*.ico", "/assets/*.*")
    .permitAll()

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you refresh a page, you need to respond index.html with the same url, so simple redirect is not enough.

Here is a solution that took my day off:

```
@Configuration
class SpaConfig @Autowired constructor(
    @Value("classpath:/frontend/index.html")
    private val indexRes: Resource
) {
    @Bean
    fun spaResourceHandlerRegistrationCustomizer() = ResourceHandlerRegistrationCustomizer { registration ->
        registration.resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(object : ResourceResolver {
                override fun resolveResource(
                    exchange: ServerWebExchange?,
                    requestPath: String,
                    locations: MutableList<out Resource>,
                    chain: ResourceResolverChain
                ): Mono<Resource> = Mono.just(indexRes)

                override fun resolveUrlPath(
                    resourcePath: String,
                    locations: MutableList<out Resource>,
                    chain: ResourceResolverChain
                ): Mono<String> = Mono.empty()
            })
}
```

This way we don't hardcode '/api' or any else prefix. index.html is served with default spring ResourceWebHandler so it supports last modified header, ranges, etc. The url in browser does not change so it will not break your frontend logic. 404 responses from API are also handled correctly.

Comment: This should be a much more rated solution. This is only one solution that works correctly for SPA applications and does not break or slow down other things. Thx.
I would recommend you to add here some check that its not a resource file. Checking that the route is not contains a dot. So as a base I extended default PathResourceResolver;

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `AntPathMatcher` from `org.springframework.util` if you want a similar behavior to how it was handled in the MVC/servlet world.  That way you can set up a configuration file, or hard-code routes like `/some-route/**` or `/another-route/**` so you can handle nested client side routes such as `/some-route/123/sub-route`.  Here is how we handled it in our Groovy code:

```yaml
client:
  routes:
    - /some-route/**
    - /another-route/**
```

```
@Autowired
ClientSettings settings

@Override
Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    String path = exchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath()
    if (evaluatePath(path))  {
        return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(exchange.getRequest().mutate().path("/index.html").build()).build())
    }
    chain.filter(exchange)
}

// probably a better way to do this
boolean evaluatePath(String path) {
    def matcher = new AntPathMatcher()
    def results = settings.routes.collect {antPattern ->
        matcher.match(antPattern, path)
    }
    results.contains(true)
}
```

`settings` is a `@ConfigurationProperties` class that we inject with a list of "whitelisted" client side routes.